# IONIC BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) - device list not showing up

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I scan for BLE devices, they are found, however, after they are found I'm trying to add those devices to a list.

**PROBLEM: the list is not showing up (or is empty) on the app.**

**JS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  device_list: any[];

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController, public ble: BLE) {

  }

  scan(){
    this.device_list = [];

    this.ble.scan([], 5).subscribe(device => {

      // ADDING TO LIST
      this.device_list.push(device);

    }, error => {
      console.log('Check your bluetooth connection.');
    });

  }

}
```

If I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(device))` instead of `this.device_list.push(device)` the devices are being printed out, but I need to add them to the list & show that list on the app.

Why is this the case?

**HTML:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="scan()" color="danger" block>SCAN</button>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of device_list">
        {{item.id+"----"item.name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Ok, so apparently, the list is fine & has devices in it.

However, the list only shows up (is updated) when:

I switch to another tab and go back to this tab (which has the list)

OR

I switch to another application and go back to this application

HOW TO FIX THIS?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way of adding to the list:

```
this.device_list = device.slice();
```

Basically, the slice() operation clones the array and returns the reference to the new array. I'm thinking that because you just push data into `device_list`, the reference to the list stays the same (although the actual contents change) and thus angular does not re-render the view.

Comment: I tried doing:

`this.device_list = device.slice();`

and then

`this.device_list.push(device);`

but the error is still the same..

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Had to add NgZone (not sure what it does).

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  device_list: any[];

  constructor(private zone:NgZone, public ble: BLE) {

  }

  scan(){
    this.device_list = [];

    this.ble.scan([], 5).subscribe(device => {
      // ADD TO LIST
      this.zone.run(() => {
       this.device_list.push(device);
      });
    }, error => {
      this.app_alert('Check your bluetooth connection.');
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: What led you to this solution?

Comment: Found in some forum.

Basically, the values of *ngFor were not updating, and this somehow updates them.